# Split words and save to dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

list1 = ['fire', 'cats', 'mats', 'wats', 'mire', 'tire']

I would like to divide these words up based on the 3 last letters of each word, and save it into a dictionary.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just stupid things. I tried looping over, splitting the words form the 1 index to the last, then saving the result in an empty dictionary with the the last 3 letters as a key and words as values. It was a complete failure.

Comment: sometimes, showing completely bogus code doesn't help. At least you tried something.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `defaultdict` with `list` as default item, and append items, computing key with string slice, like this:

```
import collections

list1 = ['fire', 'cats', 'mats', 'wats', 'mire', 'tire']

d=collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in list1:
    d[i[-3:]].append(i)

print(dict(d))  # copy in a dict just for clean display (no defaultdict prefix)
```

result:

```
{'ire': ['fire', 'mire', 'tire'], 'ats': ['cats', 'mats', 'wats']}
```

Also can be done with a one-liner, not as efficient because of the inner loo which tests all the list (one-liners are trendy, but sometimes just not the best solution):

```
d = {k:[v for v in list1 if v.endswith(k)] for k in set(x[-3:] for x in list1)}
```

result:

```
{'ire': ['fire', 'mire', 'tire'], 'ats': ['cats', 'mats', 'wats']}
```

if you wanted to filter out items with not enough associated words you could do this (after having computed `d` in the first pass):

```
d = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if len(v)>2}
```

that creates a new dictionary with only key/values if there are more than 2 elements.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Also, do you know how I could completely delete a key (and it's associated values) if the number of values falls below a certain number?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for this. Great help!

Comment: The code works, but I'm just wondering if you could explain it to me. I'm completely new to default dictionaries, so I have no idea what you've done here.